# How do I allow only username for password reset form?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

By default the password reset module allows 'Username OR E-mail'. I am using a module which allows multiple user accounts with a same email address (but usernames are unique and auto-generated), so the unique user account identifier for logging in is username, I need this to be the same in case of password reset form.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how can Drupal send an email to allow users to change their password when they forget it, if more users use the same email?

Comment: The use case of this instance is related to child usage, so using a same email for all family members (children + parents). If email is used to reset password, then all accounts associated with that email get the new password. If username is used to reset password, then only that particular account gets the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following module solves the issue as it has an option to make the reset form 'username only'.
https://www.drupal.org/project/sharedemail_pass_reset/